# how to add page 1 of n in Magento PDF invoice footer - Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, invoice, pdf

I'm facing problem for adding a number of pages in single invoice.
For example one invoice has 3 pages and I wanted to display first page 1 of 3 in  pdf invoice and second page, page 2 of 3 and last page 3 of 3 on PDF invoice.

How to implement this page of n in PDF invoice in magento?

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` class via the

> Magento_root/app/code/local/Mage

directory or rewrite it in your custom extension.

Since you need to know a total of pages, so you need to redefine the `_afterGetPdf` function of the **parent** class (`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract`) and add the following code:

```
protected function _afterGetPdf()
{
    $pages = $this->_getPdf()->pages;
    $total = count($pages);

    $current = 1;
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('page %d of %d', $current, $total), 35, 30, 'UTF-8');
        $current++;
    }

    parent::_afterGetPdf();
}
```

Also, you can play with coordinates for moving your text.

Please pay attention that the point with the 0,0 coordinates is in the lower left corner.

Also you can try to take advantage of the `getAlignRight` and the `getAlignCenter` functions of the **parent** class (`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract`).

Comment: how can we do this for magento 2?